# Is it possible to change the styling of the contents of a webview?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webview, electron

I'm wanting to load a `webview` in my [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application and then adjust the styling of the object's contents. Whether by JS or CSS is irrelevant, I just want to be able to `.hide()` or `visibility: none` elements inside the `webview`.

Is this possible? It's proven difficult to discover. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are running the latest electron version, so based on webview [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/web-view-tag/) I guess you could try this:

Inserting CSS

```
//Append CSS code do page
var myWebview = ;// your webview  definition
myWebview.insertCSS("body{background:#000}");
```

Or you could run a javascript code using `executeJavascriptCode`

```js
var myWebview = ;// your webview  definition
myWebview.executeJavaScript("$('.mySelector').hide();");
```

But in both cases I suggest you to read file contents and pass it as function arguments or append your file your to your `webview` using `executeJavascriptCode`. Check the example below:

```js
// appending javascript code 
var scriptPath = __dirname + '/path/to/script.js';
var myWebview  = ;// your webview  definition
myWebview.executeJavaScript('document.write(\'<script src="' + scriptPath + '"></script>\');');

// appending CSS code 
var cssPath   = __dirname + '/path/to/stylesheet.js';
var myWebview = ;// your webview  definition
myWebview.executeJavaScript('document.write(\'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + cssPath + '">\');');
```

Hope it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you post some code for me please? Than will be easier to check what's going on